# Weld 3.0.1 failed to work on Jetty 9.4.7

Tags: weld, jetty-9

I have a web application that used Weld 2.4.1 and Jetty 9.4.7. I tried to migrate it to Weld 3(that was the only change) and now Jetty failed to load my application with exception:

Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Decorator
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:586)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Weld Maven dependency:

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
                </dependency>
```

And app.xml(is is required to put to webapps folder according to http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html/environments.html#_jetty)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/app</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/app.war</Set>
  <Call name="prependServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler</Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call name="prependServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder</Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call name="prependServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler</Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call name="prependServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder</Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

Please, advise.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue. Looking for other alternatives. Jersey and CDI are really painful.